# Cannot establish a network connect to VMWare Fusion VM

Tags: networking, ubuntu, osx-snow-leopard, vmware-fusion

I am running Snow Leopard 10.6.2 (not the server edition) with VMWare Fusion 3.0.0 and I trying to get my Ubuntu 9.10 x86_64 VM working. I am using a bridged connection, and I have an internet connection FROM the Ubuntu VM (I can download updates, ping websites, etc), but I cannot connect TO the Ubuntu box from any other device on my network.

I am trying to get Mongrel up on the Ubuntu VM for some Rails stuff, but it's not working. I know Mongrel/Rails is not the problem because if I start the server on the Ubuntu VM, background the process, and then wget the index page, it works. I just cannot connect to the site from another IP.

I have tried using a static IP and a DHCP IP configuration on the Ubuntu VM, neither work (for incoming connections, both work for outwards). I have port scanned the Ubuntu VM, and it appears that all ports are closed. However, the Ubuntu VM does respond to pings.

I noticed a similar question here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/99757/setting-up-a-bridged-network-with-vmware-fusion, but no answer. Any ideas?

Comment: also - i really doubt this is an issue, but the snow leopard is running on a hackintosh.

Answer (score 1):

If the VM is responding to pings then the virtual network bridging is working. I would proceed by making certain that there are no software firewalls in place on either the Ubuntu VM, the Host OSX platform or your physical network that might be blocking the specific traffic (port\protocol) that you are trying to use.

There is a useful explanation and discussion on Fusion's network modes on the [Vmware Communities website here](http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-2527) that may give you some additional pointers, in particular it seems that there may be some issues with some Wireless LANs.

Comment: i can't really imagine ubuntu server comes with a firewall that locks down all ports by default. i don't know enough about linux networking to know where to start though. any recommendations?

Comment: True enough - I'm pretty sure that Ubuntu's default settings for both client and server is that firewalling is disabled. The relevant wiki page on the standard firewall (ufw) for 8.04 an later is here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall?action=show&redirect=UbuntuFirewall#Features